# Determine instance IP or DNS for Stopped instance with no EIP assigned

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3

I looked in the AWS documentation, but can't find, if an stopped instance might launch with an IP once I start it. I'm scripting something with boto3 and python, but neither `boto3.resource` nor `boto3.client` have given successful information.

Comment: You wish to know what private IP address the instance will have once it is restarted?

Answer (score 0):

The public IP is released when you [stop the instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html#instance_stop).  For a stopped instance:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='your_profile')
ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.Instance('i-09f00f00f00')
print(instance.public_ip_address)
```

Returns: `None`

To get the private IP from your instance ID (running or stopped instance):

```
print(instance.network_interfaces_attribute[0]['PrivateIpAddress'])
```

Returns: `10.0.0.200`

Reference: [Boto / EC2 / Instance / network_interfaces_attribute](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.network_interfaces_attribute)

Comment: Hi a.out, yes. the problem is not the PrivateIpAddress, but the public one. I want to know if a instance even if stopped had a public ip address.

Comment: Hi, no, the former public IP of a stopped instance is not recorded.